# Display network graph

Tags: c#, visual-studio

The below image is the wireless network graph found in `TaskManager`.

I am currently making a simple wireless network analyzer and I wanted to show a graph like the below image, so is there any library for this? if not then how can I possible display this kind of network graph?

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a library to create graphs or to get data from the network adapter?

Comment: I already done getting data from network adapter, what I wanted to add now in my project is a network graph like in Windows TaskManager, so basically a Library for creating a graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using WPF you can use the Live Charts. 
Link: https://lvcharts.net/

Instalation should be simple enough: https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Install